# Is "square" a synonym for "roundabout" (noun)?

Tags: synonyms

I can't seem to find it in a dictionary, but every once in a while (although rarely) I do seem to come across examples, such as [Bartel-Pritchard Square](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Bartel-Pritchard+Square,+Prospect+Park+Southwest,+Brooklyn,+NY+11215/@40.6609383,-73.979789,19z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x89c25b1c2b83e18b:0xa83ce8fd9e90157d), that seem to indicate the two are synonyms.

Are they? Is it a regional thing (American/British/etc.)? Or is it a misunderstanding of the word?

Comment: Interesting.. Have you considered the possibility that the particular place you mention has been a "square" historically and at some point a roundabout was placed there in as a part of urban development (for easing the traffic flow, for example)

Comment: @posdef: I had not! Are you suggesting that's generally the case, or are you just pointing it out for that particular one? (e.g. [another example](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Centre+Square,+Easton,+PA+18042/@40.6911487,-75.2090544,19z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x89c46c51103ae84d:0xe4ac4e3d4945809a))

Comment: *Square* does often awkward duty in English for any open area in a city-scape regardless of shape. We seem to have no more geometrically generic term like German *Platz,* Czech *Náměstí,* or Greek Πλατεία. A circular space may be called *Circle* or (much less frequent) *Circus,* but even it, as your link demonstrates, can have the label *Square* applied to it.

Comment: Mehrdad: I meant for that specific example, but I think it might be plausible explanation in general. It's partially connected with @BrianDonovan's comment regarding the word "square" having another meaning that has, over the years, diverged from the geometric shape.

Comment: @BrianDonovan - Actually, "plaza" is fairly generic, but, in the US at least, it tends to be viewed as a pedestrian-only space (with some exceptions, I'm sure).

Comment: You can have a roundabout without a square, and a square without a roundabout, and a roundabout in a square.  They are not synonyms.

Answer (score 3):

A [***roundabout***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/roundabout) (mainly BrE) is a [***traffic*** circle](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/traffic%20circle) - a junction of several roads consisting of a central (usually circular) island around which traffic moves in one direction.

A [***square***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/square) is an *open, typically four-sided, area surrounded by buildings*.

*Roundabouts* exist to help ***car drivers*** get around. *Squares* are public spaces where ***people/pedestrians*** congregate (large ones may be called *plazas*).

Here's [Old Street Roundabout](http://www.standard.co.uk/news/london/cycling-campaigners-claim-riders-still-face-death-trap-despite-proposed-changes-to-old-street-9856120.html) in London, which *could be transformed into a pedestrian square...*

[image]

Although because of the shape some people might call this one a "squareabout"<sup>**1**</sup>, it's not yet a "square" because pedestrians can't really get to it.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> There's a [Holiday Inn](http://www.parkwoodtheatres.co.uk/theatre/content.aspx?id=43&hid=&zid=2) just up the road from me that gives its address as *The Squareabout*, because it's in the middle of a large and relatively square roundabout.

Comment: Just so you know, here in Colorado they are only known as roundabouts. Honest.

Comment: @tchrist: In the UK we call the big ones [gyratories](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gyratory) - here are a few references calling my pictured one [the Old Street **gyratory**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22old+street+gyratory%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl).